# In WebFlux-WebFilter, how can I identify whether an inbound HTTP request has a body or not?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, netty, reactor

In WebFilter, how can I identify whether an inbound HTTP request has a body or not? I am aware of the *[Content-Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_request_fields)* header presence check, but it's a hack at the best. Besides, it will not catch all the cases (some of the clients are sending the body without the *Content-Length* header).

Note: I just need to identify whether the body is there or not, reading body is a whole different question!

The server is [Netty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netty_(software)), if that helps.

Comment: `serverWebExchange.getRequest().getBody().filter(it -> it.readableByteCount() == 0)` ? or another methods?

Comment: @Numichi : As stated in the question :`reading body is a whole different question`. Once the body consumed, it may prevent filter chain to reuse it. To rephrase the author : is there a *reliable* way to detect presence of a request body *without* consuming it ?

Comment: @Numichi Thanks for your comment
This will do me any good if spring decide to subscribe the body. For whatever reason if it doesnt do it, I am toast

Comment: to me knowledge there's only two type of request that come with body: request with `content-length` header and request with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, so I probably suggest to check for these two conditions ( that's probably how's the server (tomcat/netty) underlying works as well )

Comment: `serverWebExchange.getRequest().getBody().hasElements()` !? (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#hasElements-- ;)

Comment: but i not fully agree on the point that "reading" is not the same as "checking existence" (esp. in case the body is empty)

Answer (score 1):

In WebFlux you can use the 'HttpMessageReader' interface to determine whether an inbound HTTP request has a body or not. This interface is used to read the body of a request, so you can check if there is a registered 'HttpMessageReader' that supports the 'Content-Type' of the request.

If there is such a reader, then the request has a body; if not, then the request doesn't have a body.

Sample code:

```java
HttpMessageReader httpMessageReader = new HttpMessageReader();
if (httpMessageReader.canRead(MyRequestType.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
    // if canRead returns true, there is a body
} else {
    // if canRead returns false, there is no body
}
```

Comment: Hi Pelle, Thanks, this looks promising, do you have any sample code

Comment: Hi @so-random-dude , I have edited the original answer to include some sample code. Is this what you were looking for?